# Mandrill - send draft version of template

Tags: email, templates, mandrill

I have a template named "Basic" that has two versions, different from each other - a draft one and the published one. Is there a way - through Mandrill API - to send the draft version, not the published one - or just in general to choose which version of the two to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't published the template before, when you use the send-template api call, the draft version should be sent. The draft vs. published option is generally to allow editing an already-published template in the application without affecting what's being sent via the API. If you have already published the template, and also have a draft, then in the web interface in the test menu is an option to send a test, which should allow you to send a test of the draft version instead of the published version.

Comment: Which if your template is only a partial to be inserted into a container template, or if it contains any merge variables, there's no way to test send using the draft code for a template. Which is unfortunate.